# What are the various errors/issues associated with Azure Data services, that might occur during runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to work with the predictive-preventive anomaly detection and resolution model, for which I want to list all errors/parameters that affect the working of Azure Data Service(Data lake, data factory, etc)and might lead to service failure i.e those issues that might occur in the future, eg the container size reaching its maximum limit, or any such issues.
I have tried going through the majority of issues/errors listed in Microsoft documentation and posts related to each specific service, but they all fall under reactive maintenance(reactive anomaly detection and resolution).

Answer (score 0):

There can't be any exact answer to your question. When you deploy and configure any service, there might be any issue and any error which can occur.

Though, **the major common issues you can face would be related to storage, compute and connectivity**. Therefore, it is recommended to keep monitoring the health of services.

When you deploy any files in Azure Data Lake, scalability is not the big issue because **Azure Storage is scalable by design whether you access via Data Lake Storage Gen2 or Blob storage interfaces. It is able to store and serve many exabytes of data. This amount of storage is available with throughput measured in gigabits per second (Gbps) at high levels of input/output operations per second (IOPS). Processing is executed at near-constant per-request latencies that are measured at the service, account, and file levels.** So, when you connect the ADLS with Analytic services, e.g.; Databricks and Synapse, just take care of the connectivity and compute infrastructure (RAM and Memory). Make sure your compute infrastructure is powerful enough to process adequate amount of data as per your requirement.

In Azure Data Factory, compute infrastructure is called Integration Runtime (IR). When you deploy the ADF, a default Azure IR is assigned to you which is responsible to run your pipelines. If the load increases, you need to reconfigure or create a new IR for better stability. You can visit [Create and configure Azure Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) to create new IR.

Similarly, for each Azure data service, you need to consider similar issues.

At the end, it is a good approach if you deploy [Azure Service Health](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/service-health/#overview) to monitor the performance and other issues related to your services.

Comment: So, basically, the parameters related to connectivity and processing can be used as the hyperparameters in the predictive-preventive anomaly detection and resolution model.

Comment: Yes, processing majorly.